# Accessing apex webservice/SOAP method from PHP

Tags: soap, php

I am trying to call a SF method from a remote PHP script. I am using github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP.

Method has been set as a webservice :

```
global class groupCamp {
    webservice static void method() {
        // some HTTP requests & mails here
    }
}
```

PHP code :

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
require_once ('soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');

// connection
$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml");
// question 1
$mySforceConnection->setEndPoint("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0");

define("USERNAME", …);
define("PASSWORD", …);
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", …);

$login = $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);
$client = new SoapClient("groupCamp.xml");
$header = new SoapHeader("http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/groupCamp", "SessionHeader",
  ["sessionId" => $mySforceConnection->getSessionId()]);
$client->__setSoapHeaders([$header]);

// question 2
$client->__setLocation(get_object_vars($login)['serverUrl']);


try {
    $client->method();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fwrite(fopen("SalesforceToGroupcamp.log", 'a'), date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." : ".$e->getMessage()." : ".$e->getLine()."\n".$e->getTraceAsString());
}
```

I get the error :

```
No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/groupCamp}mymethod
```

Question 1 : What am I supposed to put here : same version number as API I guess ? And why /u/ or /c/ ?

Question 2 : is this how I am supposed to define location ? Or is this with setEndpoint, or in the header ?

Comment: Adding that it works perfectly on the sandbox.

Comment: Tried with /s/ too, both in the login & request endpoints.

Comment: I get **cs87**.salesforce.com/services/Soap/ **c** /36.0/00D8E0000008vrW on sandbox and **eu2**.salesforce.com/services/Soap/ **m** /36.0/00Db0000000HwPa in prod… is this normal ?

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution to this?